# How to set wifi option in the iPhone UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities plist?

Tags: iphone, plist

My app uses an internet connection. I think I need to set the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the plist with some sort of wifi/cellular property.

Does anyone know the correct keys I need to add?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you *might* be after the "UIRequiresPersistentWiFi" key.

See the [Information Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) document for the full list of keys.

Answer (score 1):

Reference this tech document

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1397.html

Comment: Interesting I'm trying to think of a scenario where I would want to prohibit iPhone users from downloading an app designed for the touch...

Answer (score 0):

This should be done in code. Look at the Reachability.h libraries. As far as I know all the iOS devices have WiFi so this would be a pointless key.

Comment: The Chinese iPhones don't have Wifi.

Answer (score -2):

All current (and past) shipping iOS devices have internet capability.  So no such key exists.

Whether the user has turned one or more of them on is something an installed app has to determine at run-time.